# My clang-complete doesn't run well in my Vim

Tags: vim, clang-complete

I installed `clang-complete` by using Vundle,and downloaded llvm using `sudo apt install llvm-4.0`, downloaded clang by using `sudo apt install libclang-4.0`.Here is my .vimrc:

```
let g:clang_complete_auto=1     " automatically complete after -> . ::
let g:clang_hl_errors=1         " highlight the warnings and error the same way clang does it
let g:clang_complete_copen=0    " open quickfix window on error
let g:clang_periodic_quickfix=0 " periodically update the quickfix window
let g:clang_snippets=0
let g:clang_close_preview=1
let g:clang_use_library=1
let g:clang_library_path='/usr/lib/llvm-4.0/lib'
let g:clang_user_options='-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -I /usr/include/c++/8/'
set completeopt=menu,longest
```

However, it doesn't run well in this way. When I type `std::`, the menu only shows some useless items such as `size_t` but except `cout` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the `Troubleshooting` section in the [README](https://github.com/xavierd/clang_complete/blob/master/README.md) of your plugin. It says that the first step is to check `completefunc` and `omnifunc` when in your C++ buffer, and then to check the output of `:messages`. I think that knowing what those settings are at runtime of your Vim would show us what's going on.

If `completefunc` isn't set, then there's something going on with one of your settings; the plugin is trying to do what it does, but one of your settings are improperly formatted (or something like that.) The output of `:messages` should be able to show you which setting this is, as well.